# Multithreaded program with mutex on mutual resource

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I tried to build a program which should create threads and assign a Print function to each one of them, while the main process should use printf function directly.

Firstly, I made it without any synchronization means and expected to get a randomized output.
Later I tried to add a mutex to the Print function which was assigned to the threads and expected to get a chronological output but it seems like the mutex had no effect about the output.

Should I use a mutex on the printf function in the main process as well?

Thanks in advance

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

pthread_t threadID[20];
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void* Print(void* _num);

int main(void)
{
    int num = 20, indx = 0, k = 0;

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL))
    {
        perror("err pthread_mutex_init\n");
        return errno;
    }

    for (; indx < num; ++indx)
    {
        if (pthread_create(&threadID[indx], NULL, Print, &indx))
        {
            perror("err pthread_create\n");
            return errno;   
        }
    }

    for (; k < num; ++k)
    {
        printf("%d from main\n", k);
    }

    indx = 0; 

    for (; indx < num; ++indx)
    {
        if (pthread_join(threadID[indx], NULL))
        {
            perror("err pthread_join\n");
            return errno;   
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    return 0;
}


void* Print(void* _indx)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    printf("%d from thread\n", *(int*)_indx);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by chronological output?

Comment: AFAICR,  pthread functions don’t set errno.  They return the error number.

Comment: You need to pass a different pointer to each thread to get deterministic results. The value in `indx` may change before the thread runs.

Comment: The mutex here ensures that only one thread at a time can call the `printf` statement, that's all it does.

Comment: ... and you don't need a mutex for that.

Comment: I expected to something like that...
1 from thread
1 from main
2 from thread
2 from main
3 from thread
3 from main

What do you mean different pointer? I have array of thread....
What should I do to make sure that every time a thread runs, it runs with different indx?

Comment: @John Bollinger: Smells like homework, and I've used stdio libraries that blew up if you tried this without the mutex.

Comment: @Joshua a stdio library that blows up under those circumstances does not conforming to either [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_01) or [C](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.2p7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All questions of program bugs notwithstanding, pthreads mutexes provide *only* **mut**ual **ex**clusion, not any guarantee of scheduling order.  This is typical of mutex implementations.  Similarly, `pthread_create()` only creates and starts threads; it does not make any guarantee about scheduling order, such as would justify an assumption that the threads reach the `pthread_mutex_lock()` call in the same order that they were created.

Overall, if you want to *order* thread activities based on some characteristic of the threads, then you have to manage that yourself.  You need to maintain a sense of which thread's turn it is, and provide a mechanism sufficient to make a thread notice when it's turn arrives.  In some circumstances, with some care, you can do this by using semaphores instead of mutexes.  The more general solution, however, is to use a *condition variable* together with your mutex, and some shared variable that serves as to indicate who's turn it currently is.

Comment: Thank you and Martin for these answers, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The code passes the address of the same local variable to all threads. Meanwhile, this variable gets updated by the main thread.

Instead pass it by value cast to `void*`.

Fix:

```
pthread_create(&threadID[indx], NULL, Print, (void*)indx)
// ...
printf("%d from thread\n", (int)_indx);
```

Now, since there is no data shared between the threads, you can remove that mutex.

Comment: I don't really understand what is the problem with the indx address and how the void* casting solves it?

I use -Werror and it does't let me do the casting you offered because of different sizes of integer and pointer.

Comment: @Sexymf Use `intptr_t` instead of `int` then.

Comment: What is intptr_t and why should I use it instead of int?
Can you please explain the first problem with the indx address and the void*?

Comment: @Sexymf See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer: _integer type capable of holding a pointer_.

Comment: Ok thank you
One last question, does it change something if I write &indx or (void*)indx ?

Comment: @Sexymf `&indx` and `(void*)indx` are very different things. The first is the address of variable `indx`, the latter is a copy of `indx` value stored in `void*`.

Answer (score 0):

All the threads created in the for loop have different value of *indx*. Because of the operating system scheduler, you can never be sure which thread will run. Therefore, the values printed are in random order depending on the randomness of the scheduler. The second for-loop running in the parent thread will run immediately after creating the child threads. Again, the scheduler decides the order of what thread should run next.

Every OS should have an interrupt (at least the major operating systems have). When running the for-loop in the parent thread, an interrupt might happen and leaves the scheduler to make a decision of which thread to run. Therefore, the numbers being printed in the parent for-loop are printed randomly, because all threads run "concurrently".

Joining a thread means waiting for a thread. If you want to make sure you print all numbers in the parent for loop in chronological order, without letting child thread interrupt it, then relocate the for-loop section to be after the thread joining.